# Append date, time to batch log file

Tags: date, batch-file, logging

I have batch script that stop, start windows services:

`net stop Tomcat6 1>>C:\logs\"%date%"\log.txt 2>&1`

but in this log I have only information, that "service is stopping" and "service has been stopped". How could modify this script to append in front of every output message to have %date%-%time% ?

Answer (score 3):

Use a `for/f` loop to capture each line of your command (you have to redirect STDERR here, or it would be lost). Then just echo date, time and the captured line.

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
(for /f "tokens=*" %%a in ('"net stop Tomcat6 2>&1"') do (
  echo !date!-!time! %%a
))>"C:\logs\%date%\log.txt"
```

Note: depending on your locale settings, you may have to adapt the date string in `"C:\logs\%date%\log.txt"` to make it a valid folder\filename.

Answer (score 0):

I Hope This Will Help For you.

```
@echo off
echo.
echo %date% %time% && net stop service_Name >>%systemdrive%\Log\Logs.txt 2>&1
::ping www.google.com >nul
::For Slow Run,Remove Comments (Remove This line also)
Exit
```

Comment: That code tries to execute `%date% %time%` There is at least an echo and a pair of parentheses missing. Also this will infinitely trying to stop the service

Comment: Scripts usually run infinitely in Background Processes.You Can change/Edit Script as you Want.

Comment: technique is important.